# User name is not showing in web page from database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I've made a login script in JSP. It's working fine but the problem as i use 
`<%=session.getAttribute("first_name")%>` it shows `Null`. Can you please tell me what's wrong here?

`Main.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <%
    if ((session.getAttribute("user_email") == null) || (session.getAttribute("user_email") == "")) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
%>
<%} else
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to the job seeker forum.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_styles/forum_style.css"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.1-alpha-20141011' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid|Exo:800|Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,600|Roboto:400,100,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="forum">
        <h1><b>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("first_name")%></b>,<br>to Job seeker forum, there are many openings that you can get through here. <a href='logout.jsp'>logout</a></h1>
        <form id="forum_form" method="post">
        </form>
    </div><br><br><br>
    <div id="forum2">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Want to post on going walking,<br>Post your job description here.</h1>
        <form id="forum2_form" method="post">
            <p>
            <label>Job title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="e.g XXX Referral program for freshers."/>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Your Question:</label>
            <textarea class="question_ask_style" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Type description here.."></textarea>
            </p>

            <div id="submit_btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Question" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is `login_process.jsp`

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
    String user_email=request.getParameter("user_email");
    String user_password=request.getParameter("user_password");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/login", "root", "1234");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from members where email='"+user_email+"' and password='"+user_password+"'");

    if(rs.next()){
        session.setAttribute("user_email", user_email);
        response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");
    }else{
        out.println("Invalid Password... Try again.. <a href='login.jsp'>login</a>");
    }
%>
```

Here is my created `database table`:

```
create table `members`(
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)ENGINE= InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

This is what i'm getting error...

**SCREENSHOT**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuF5M.png

Comment: You're not setting the `first_name` session attribute, so obviously cannot get it.

Comment: where is session.setAttribute() for first_name ?

Comment: So, How to get session attribute, i just get stuck .. how to write it becoz it never calls from database..

Comment: You can get first_name from ResultSet rs, as you are querying Select * from Menmbers table and you can get the first_name details from members table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `login_process.jsp` use `<%=session.setAttribute("first_name",first_name)%>` and then access it.
eg:

```
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from members where email='"+user_email+"' and password='"+user_password+"'");

        if(rs.next()){
            session.setAttribute("first_name", rs.getString("first_name"));//set first_name in session
            session.setAttribute("user_email", user_email);

            response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%=session.getAttribute("first_name")%>` shows `null` because you have not set the `first_name` in the session.

You have set the only the `user_email`.

```
if(rs.next()){
        String user_email=rs.getString("first_name");
        session.setAttribute("user_email", user_email);
        response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");
```

you can set like the above

P.S

Scriptlets are discouraged over the decades , so it is advised to use EL instead of them . You can simply use , `${sessionScope.user_email}` to print it out in the jsp page

Comment: So, How to get `session attribute`, i just get stuck .. how to write it becoz it never calls from database..

Comment: You may set it on login_process.jsp as`<%=session.setAttribute("first_name",first_name)%>`

Comment: but dude, it says `first_name` is unknown variable.. So how to initialize it?? .. there i really get stuck.. pls help :(

Comment: do you have first name in the `members` table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(rs.next()){
    session.setAttribute("user_email", user_email);

    session.setAttribute("first_name", rs.getString(4));//Add this line to your code


    response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");
}
```

Here 4 is column number for first_name

Answer (score 0):

in login_process.jsp set

```
session.setAttribute("user_email", user_email);
```

to

```
    session.setAttribute("first_name", rs.getString("first_name"));
```

because you have set the attribute name user_email and getting first_name from session.